# Visual Studio docker-compose project adds incorrect build target during Debug build

Tags: visual-studio, docker, docker-compose

I have a dotnet core API project setup with a Dockerfile that is pretty much the default one that it creates from the template.

I then added a docker-compose project to the Solution, again it's pretty much the default.

I get the same project with the same eShopOnContainers sample project https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers using Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise 16.5.5

If I run a debug build, it generates docker-compose.vs.debug.g.yml which includes the target: base line. This is snippet of the Output pane

```
========== Preparing Containers ==========
Getting Docker containers ready...
docker-compose  -f "Z:\eShopOnContainers\src\docker-compose.yml" -f "Z:\eShopOnContainers\src\docker-compose.override.yml" -f "Z:\eShopOnContainers\src\obj\Docker\docker-compose.vs.debug.g.yml" -p dockercompose14238446180031813375 --no-ansi config
The INSTRUMENTATION_KEY variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
The ORCHESTRATOR_TYPE variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
The ESHOP_SERVICE_BUS_USERNAME variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
The ESHOP_SERVICE_BUS_PASSWORD variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
The ESHOP_AZURE_STORAGE_CATALOG_NAME variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
The ESHOP_AZURE_STORAGE_CATALOG_KEY variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
The ESHOP_AZUREFUNC_CAMPAIGN_DETAILS_URI variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
The ESHOP_AZURE_STORAGE_MARKETING_NAME variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
The ESHOP_AZURE_STORAGE_MARKETING_KEY variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
services:
  basket-api:
    build:
      context: Z:\eShopOnContainers\src
      dockerfile: Services/Basket/Basket.API/Dockerfile
      labels:
        com.microsoft.created-by: visual-studio
        com.microsoft.visual-studio.project-name: Basket.API
      target: base
    container_name: Basket.API
    depends_on:
    - basketdata
    - identity-api
    - rabbitmq
```

From the Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
```

base target doesn't contain anything so this doesn't work

Release build does not include the target: base line and so works.

This seems like a bug in VS but am I missing something or some setting somewhere?